# Finsler Metric from page 2 of the book by Chern and Shen.

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, differential

Physicist here not a mathematician.  I am trying to understand the notation for the Finsler metric in Chern and Shen's book.

The equation is

$$\textbf{g}_y(u,v):=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s \partial t} \left[ F^2( y + su + tv) \right]_{s=t=0} ~.$$

Normally I would have written something like

$$ \textbf{g}(u,v)= \frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial^2 F^2}{\partial u\partial v} u v~. $$

If I make substitutions $a=su$ and $b=tv$, evaluation of the top equation gives me

$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial^2 F^2(y)}{\partial a\partial b} uv ~.$$

Which is not the middle equation.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that if you don't get a helpful response here, PhysicsStackExchange is another good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of notation in the book is that $u,v $ are vectors and $s,t$ are scalars. So the composition $F^2(y+su+tv)$ is a function of two scalar variables $s,t$. We take second mixed partial of that function.

What you wrote in the second equation may be familiar to you, but I do not recognize "partial derivative with respect to a vector" as a precise mathematical concept.